# DependencyProperty not working on CustomControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm trying to make a custom control, with some custom properties, however when attempting to Bind to the property it doesn't seem to work.

Here is my Code Behind **UserProfile.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Controls
{
    public class UserProfile : Control
    {
        static UserProfile()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(UserProfile),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(UserProfile)));
        }

        #region PhotoSize DP
        /// <summary>
        /// Gets or sets the Label which is displayed next to the field
        /// </summary>
        public Double PhotoSize
        {
            get { return (Double)GetValue(PhotoSizeProperty); }
            set { SetValue(PhotoSizeProperty, value); }
        }
        /// <summary>
        /// Identified the Label dependency property
        /// </summary>
        public static readonly DependencyProperty PhotoSizeProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("PhotoSize", typeof(Double),
              typeof(UserProfile), null);
        #endregion
    }
}
```

**XAML - Generic.xaml**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:UserProfile}">
        <Setter Property="DataContext" Value="{x:Type local:UserProfile}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:UserProfile}">
                    <Grid x:Name="circleGrid" Width="{Binding PhotoSize}">
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <RowDefinition Height="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=circleGrid}" />
                            <RowDefinition />
                            <RowDefinition />
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Border x:Name="circleBorder"
                                Grid.Row="0"
                                CornerRadius="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=circleGrid}"
                                Width="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=circleGrid}"
                                Height="{Binding Path=ActualWidth, ElementName=circleGrid}"
                                BorderBrush="White"
                                BorderThickness="3">
                            <Border.Background>
                                <ImageBrush ImageSource="D:\Users\Martyn Ball\Pictures\11061728_10153409797331063_2946862347621203654_o.jpg" Stretch="UniformToFill" />
                            </Border.Background>
                        </Border>

                        <WrapPanel Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <TextBlock x:Name="firstName"
                                       FontWeight="Bold"
                                       Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                       Text="Martyn" />
                            <TextBlock Text=" "/>
                            <TextBlock x:Name="lastName"
                                       FontWeight="Normal"
                                       Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                                       Text="Ball" />
                        </WrapPanel>

                        <WrapPanel Grid.Row="2">
                            <WrapPanel Margin="5">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="imageDifference" Text="" />
                                <TextBlock Text="56" />
                            </WrapPanel>
                            <WrapPanel Margin="5">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="earningsDifference" Text="£" />
                                <TextBlock Text="£50.50" />
                            </WrapPanel>
                        </WrapPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

**Error:**

> BindingExpression path error: 'PhotoSize' property not found on
>   'object' ''RuntimeType' (HashCode=19976800)'.
>   BindingExpression:Path=PhotoSize; DataItem='RuntimeType'
>   (HashCode=19976800); target element is 'Grid' (Name=''); target
>   property is 'Width' (type 'Double')

Comment: "It doesn't work" - How? Any errors?

Comment: @EmpereurAiman, crap I had the error in my clipboard but forgot put it in! lol will add it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the DataContext to a `Type` (`x:Type` is doing it). You have set the `TargetType` already. So remove the line `<Setter Property="DataContext" Value="{x:Type local:UserProfile}" />` and change the `Binding`s to `TemplateBinding`s and it will work.
Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597492/what-is-the-template-binding-vs-binding) question for more info regarding the differences between `Binding` and `TemplateBinding`

Comment: Done this, still not working however there are no errors anymore.

Comment: My use of the control: `<Controls:UserProfile PhotoSize="50" />`

Comment: Oh and try using TemplateBinding inside your template.

Comment: Well the binding doesn't work, as PhotoSize should be 50, where as it's just taking up the size of the window at the moment.

Comment: Change the width to TemplateBinding and check

Comment: If I change it to `<Grid x:Name="circleGrid" Width="50">` it works fine

Comment: Change `<Grid x:Name="circleGrid" Width="{Binding PhotoSize}">` to `<Grid x:Name="circleGrid" Width="{TemplateBinding PhotoSize}">`

Comment: Ooooh that works thanks, sorry I misunderstood you, I thought `TemplateBinding` just binded to Setters already set in the style. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to have helped :) Check out this question [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597492/what-is-the-template-binding-vs-binding) question for more info regarding the differences between `TemplateBinding` and `Binding`. :)

Comment: Could you just check this? I'm getting an error saying: `The TypeConverter for "IValueConverter" does not support converting from a string`, on this line `BorderThickness="{Binding Converter=CalculateBorder, Path=Width, ElementName=circleBorder, ConverterParameter=30}">`.

Comment: That is because you are assigning a string to Converter. Put the converter into the Resources and use the {StaticResource} extension.
Like in the resources.: `<namespace:CalculateBorder x:key="converter"...`
Then in your binding, `Converter={StaticResource converter}`