# Dynamic property of a text box within a button using a button template

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, controltemplate

I have a few buttons to set up in C# WPF, and I like to use a button template.

I can set the template and then use it in my grid, but how do I change the text of the TextBox per button and also other properties like the color of the rectangle?

Here is my template:

```
<Window.Resources>
 <ControlTemplate x:Key="menuButton_Type1" TargetType="Button">
  <Grid >
   <Rectangle x:Name="Normal" Fill="#FFFDC776" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Width="82" RadiusX="7" RadiusY="7"/>
   <Rectangle x:Name="Pressed" Fill="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Width="82" RadiusX="7" RadiusY="7" Visibility="Hidden"/>
   <Rectangle x:Name="Disable" Fill="#FF707070" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="25" Width="82" RadiusX="7" RadiusY="7" Visibility="Hidden"/>
   <Border Width="82" Height="25" Padding="0,0,5,0">
    <TextBlock Text="EXIT" FontFamily="{StaticResource Swiss911}" FontSize="18" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
   </Border>
  </Grid>
  <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
   <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
    <Setter TargetName="Normal" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
    <Setter TargetName="Pressed" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
   </Trigger>
   <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
    <Setter TargetName="Normal" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
    <Setter TargetName="Disable" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
   </Trigger>
  </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
 </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

I use the template button in my XAML grid like this:

```
<Grid>
 <Button Template="{StaticResource menuButton_Type1}" Margin="18,226,-18,-226" />
</Grid>
```

I would like to change the text of the *TextBlock* currently set to "EXIT" and also the color of one of the Rectangle, in this case the normal one. How do I do this?

I tried to use dynamic properties, but that did not work for me.

Comment: To make it clear, I intend to use the template several times in my WPF Grid. This is why I want to use a template. Otherwise, of course, I can just the text of the TextBox in the template, but I want to use several buttons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found your answer on these pages:

- *[What is the template binding vs binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10597492/what-is-the-template-binding-vs-binding)*
- *[TemplateBinding Markup Extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/templatebinding-markup-extension?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)*

You can simply put the binding to the Text property of TextBlock on your ControlTemplate.

You should add the *Content* property of the button to TextBlock's text property:

```
     <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" FontFamily="{StaticResource Swiss911}" FontSize="18" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
```

Then you can set the content property of Button, the *Content* property of Button will be passing to the your *TextBlock*'s *Text* property.

```
     <Button Template="{StaticResource menuButton_Type1}" Content="Exit"  Margin="100" />
```

I tested with these *Buttons*:

```
    <Button Template="{StaticResource menuButton_Type1}" Content="Exit"  Margin="0,0,0,0" />
    <Button Template="{StaticResource menuButton_Type1}" Content="Close"  Margin="100,0,0,0" />
    <Button Template="{StaticResource menuButton_Type1}" Content="Open"  Margin="200,0,0,0" />
```

Comment: This works, I also like to change the color of the rectangle inside the grid part of the button. Do you know if I can use a different property for that?

Comment: Ok, I use the Background property of the button. It worked.

Comment: The second reference is in [Turkish](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Turkish#Proper_noun).

Comment: Thx Peter, I changed the 2nd reference.